# HTTP DELETE operations in RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp on WP8 and I've discovered an odd behavior. It might be a bug in RestSharp my code has been thoroughly reviewed and no memory issues were found.

Bellow are two scenarios which should yield the same result, but don't.

- First:

  1. I do a POST operation - returns an ObjectId
  2. I do a DELETE operation on the ObjectId - returns "OK"
  3. I do a GET operation on the ObjectId - returns "NotFound" - which is what I expected
- Seccond:

  1. I do a POST operation - returns an ObjectId
  2. I do a GET operation on the ObjectId - returns Object from which I extract the ObjectId
  3. I do a DELETE operation on the extracted ObjectId - returns "OK"
  4. I do a GET operation on the extracted ObjectId - returns Object (!) - it should return "NotFound"

The server performs the actual DELETE in both cases (confirmed by the DBA and by JMeter tests), so this means data is being saved somewhere and returned.

Has anyone ever encountered behavior such as this? Or does RestSharp have any known issues relating to this?

Comment: What response code do you get in the response to GET in step 4?

Comment: I receive code 200 - OK

Comment: Ok can you rule out that it's an issue with your code by making the REST request call steps using cURL or hurl.it? When you do so, do you observe the same results?

Comment: Hm I'm using a modified version of Apache JMeter to test my requests, and all my tests return the expected results. I'm thinking maybe there's something within the RestSharp API that's faulty. I'll look into hurl.it, thank you!